# selecting all columns with a specific character snowflake

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have a table with 120 columns, and am trying to select all columns starting with 'ES'.I am sure it will be a wildcard application.
Can I please get help on how to query columns with above condition? Help is appreciated

Comment: You need to use the INFORMATION_SCHEMA

Comment: If this is a common use-case, I'd recommend creating a view that only has the ES* fields in it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

select COLUMN_NAME from "MYDATABASE"."INFORMATION_SCHEMA"."COLUMNS" where left(COLUMN_NAME,2) = 'ES' and TABLE_NAME = 'MyTable'